# Proper way to wrap dash using rlwrap

Tags: signals, readline, dash

On Ubuntu, I have set `alias sh='rlwrap --complete-filenames sh'` to get readline keybindings and filename completion when using the dash shell (on my computer, sh is /usr/bin/sh, which is a symbolic link to /usr/bin/dash). However, rlwrap does not seem to handle SIGTSTP correctly. Consider the following shell session:

In bash:

```
user@example.com:~$ alias sh='rlwrap --complete-filenames sh'
user@example.com:~$ sh  # Run dash.
```

In dash:

```
$ sleep 100  # Right after this, I press Ctrl-Z to send SIGTSTP.
[1]+  Stopped                 rlwrap --complete-filenames sh
user@example.com:~$  # What!? Why do I get a bash prompt!?
```

When I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>z</kbd>, `dash` is stopped instead of `sleep`. How do I make SIGTSTP stop the foreground process running in dash, instead of stopping dash itself? What is the correct way to use rlwrap with dash?

I know that as an alternative to rlwrap, I could compile dash with libedit (`./configure --with-libedit`) to get readline functionality (using `dash -E`), but unfortunately that does not seem to support filename completion.

Comment: Why?  dash is a good shell for running scripts, if you don't need newer features like arrays.  It makes a lousy, minimalist interactive shell.  Just use bash, ksh, or zsh for interactive shells and for scripts where you don't care about speed and/or need arrays, and dash where shell script performance is paramount (but if decent performance is required, you should probably be writing in awk or perl or a compiled language like C instead).

Comment: "sh" should be a giveaway. For most shells, when a shell is linked to a symbolic link /bin/sh, it makes the shell behave as a POSIX-compliant minimal shell for scripting. Not to mention that dash is also the same otherwise. If the OP wants a minimal interactive shell, he can try mksh.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I make SIGTSTP stop the foreground process running in dash, instead of stopping dash itself?

This is not what you want. `rlwrap` cannot know what is in the `dash` job table and direct its anesthetic darts to one of `dash`s subprocesses accordingly.

The solution can be much simpler, however: just forward the `CTRL+Z` keypress to `dash` (by binding it to `rlwrap-direct-keypress` in your `.inputrc`).

With *current* `rlwrap` this *doesn't work*, however: `rlwrap` mirrors all `dash`s terminal settings  (including `VSUSP`, the suspend character) so `rlwrap` will never even see the keypress.

This is on my TODO list (see https://github.com/hanslub42/rlwrap/issues/111)

Hans (`rlwrap` maintainer)